# How do I create a binding that involves some sort of formula?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

As an example, if I have an element whose size I want to be twice the size of another element, how would I achieve this?

An example would be the following, `mirroredObject` is the object that I want to use half of it's width for the width of the `Border` object.

```
<Border Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mirroredObject, Mode=Default}" />
```

I have other situations where the property I might like to bind to might be the sum of the widths of other elements, how would I achieve this also?

**SOLUTION**

Please refer to my answer for the solution which was aided by lenanovd's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use binding converter that convert int to another int using your formula. For example of binding converter please read [this](http://www.dev102.com/2008/07/17/wpf-binding-converter-best-practices/) article.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for that levanovd, I've just created a converter and will add a solution to my question in case others wish to bind to other interface elements.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to levanovd for providing a hint on how to solve this problem. Following is my solution to this problem, thanks again levanovd.

**Create a converter**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class MultiplierConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof(Double))
            throw new Exception("Conversion not allowed.");
        double f, m = (double)value;
        string par = parameter as string;
        if (par == null || !Double.TryParse(par, out f)) f = 1;
        return m * f;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof(Double))
            throw new Exception("Conversion not allowed.");
        double f, m = (double)value;
        string par = parameter as string;
        if (par == null || !Double.TryParse(par, out f)) f = 1;
        return f == 0 ? float.NaN : m / f;
    }
}
```

**Add converter to your XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <n:MultiplierConverter x:Key="MultiplierConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Add binding between objects specifying argument for multiplier.**

```
<StackPanel>
  <Rectangle x:Name="source" Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
  <Rectangle Width="100" Stroke="Black"
             Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=source, Mode=Default,
                              Converter={StaticResource MultiplierConverter},
                              ConverterParameter=2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now the second rectangle will be twice the hight of the first rectangle and can be adjusted with `ConverterParameter`. Unfortunately you can't bind `ConverterParameter` to another property, not sure why that limitation exists.